# Why Is My Application Being Sent To The Fraud Department

Tags: credit-history, fraud, application-process

I have good credit and no credit problems. To verify, I just pulled a TransUnion report and it was clean. Recently, I tried to open an account at Navy Federal Credit Union. Everything was going fine, then after several weeks after I didn't get any response from them, I called them and they said they didn't open the account because they suspected fraud. They never told me. The way to "fix" that was that I had to send several pieces of ID to their fraud department verifying who I am. That was over a month ago and when I talked to a Customer Service Representative again recently they said they can't check status. I will try once more, but then I will give up on it.

Now today, I applied for a credit card totally unrelated to Navy Federal. They pulled my TransUnion credit report and said everything looked good, but then they connected me to the fraud department. Again, they are asking for documentation. Since TransUnion is the company that the credit card company used and they said my credit was great I chose the TransUnion for my free report. They like my credit, just think some type of fraud is happening!

I've never had to fill requests like this before for a credit card, bank account, etc. This can't be a coincidence. There is nothing on my credit report about fraud. Could someone have put a "ding" on me regarding fraud that I don't know about? Really confused about this.

Comment: Are you _eligible_ to open an account at Navy Federal Credit Union? Some credit unions restrict membership to specific groups of people (e.g. employees of or retirees from a company), and maybe you need to be associated with the US Navy, on active duty, or with reservist status, or honorably discharged from the Navy in order to open an account at Navy Federal Credit Union?

Comment: Have you checked your credit reports from the other two main agencies (Equifax and Experian)?  They might say something different from what Transunion says.  You also might want to check if there is negative information in [ChexSystems](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/banking/blacklisted-by-chexsystems-what-to-know/).

Comment: Did you apply for a credit card at Navy Federal or elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are number of reasons why your application got flagged. First and foremost, are you [eligible for membership](https://www.navyfederal.org/how-to-become-a-member/how-to-become-a-member.php) at Navy Federal Credit Union? Credit unions have requirements for allowing people to become members. Navy Federal has some strict requirements (i.e. Active Duty, DOD employee, etc.). So if you aren't affiliated with the US Military, they might flag your application.

For the fraud portion of your question, I have gone through the same situation. I apply for a credit card, and then I get a letter/email saying that they need me to fill out the SSA-89 form because they want to verify my identity. This is because someone else has tried to apply for a loan (credit card, mortgage, etc.) under your name, SSN, etc. They weren't successful because they probably weren't able to answer all the questions (i.e. which of the following streets did you grow up on, etc.). As a result, your information got flagged because the bank thought that someone was trying to apply using your information. So it's a good thing that the bank is being diligent about this, but it is frustrating. Your best bet would be go into a branch where you are able to speak to someone in person about this (have your ID and other appropriate documentation with you) and they can expedite it.